# Ubuntu 14.04 shows only one hdd

Tags: hard-drive

I am just started using Ubuntu & I am not computer expert. I have 2 nos of 500gb hdds mounted in my pc. First one has Ubuntu 14.04, XP & one partition for files. The other 500gb is used for dumping books, movies, songs etc.
The problem is, some time after I start pc & select Ubuntu, my other HDD is not visible or get unmounted (THE SECOND HDD WAS THERE WHEN I START, & I EVEN SAVED SOME FILES OVER INTERNET IN TO IT). I opened Disk Utility, but it shows only one HDD & there is no option to scan & re-mount second HDD.
Can somebody help me solve this problem? This is not the first time it happened. Earlier I would restart my pc & things became fine but today it happened 3rd time. So I am asking for Help. Earlier, thru XP, I chkdsk the second HDD with automatic scan & correct error option. but there were no problems.
Thanks & Regards
Dhananjay Patwardhan

Answer (score 0):

Does your hdd have SMART (self-monitoring-something - it predicts when your disk is going to be trash before it happens)? If yes, you could search for any tool that is able to read out these values (Windows: SIW, hwInfo, Defraggler - Ubuntu: ?), as your problem sounds to me like a hardware problem. Think of backing up important files, which is never a fault. If it really is a hardware problem (hdd going to die soon), you should avoid unnecessary spin-up/-downs, so keep it running as long as possible or keep it off, but avoid many restarts.